# Rewriting classes,but using the original in other pages

Tags: html, css

Lately, I see more and more a 'small' problem in my project...
I working on a project with `CSS` file with some `classes`. I see a lot rewriting of base classes like :

```
input {
//code
}
```

When comes the time when I want to use it, of course I use those  rewritten settings. What is the best way to wotk with the original settings of base classes and ignore those changes. For example use the original settings of `input`.

If it helps I have an ID for each page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could edit your css `input` to `input:not(.original)` and use `original` class to all the inputs you want use the original css.

exemple

css

```
input:not(.original){
/*your css*/
}
```

html

```
/* affected by the css*/
<input>
/* not affected by the css*/
<input class=original>
```

[Here is an exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/ywxaG/)

Or also you could change the `input` to `.input` and add the class `input` to all the input you want to use the custom css.

Comment: How should I use it, if i want to use this line with original input settings? name: `<input type="text" name="fname"><br>`

Comment: Exactly what i searched...nice answer Jonathen